# SumatraPDF as default PDF viewer in Emacs

Tags: emacs, pdf-reader, auctex

I have been trying to change the default PDF viewer in Emacs from Adobe to SumatraPDF. After searching on the internet I began editing the .emacs file. The file has a lot of stuff not concerning the .pdf viewer which I omit. This is what I think is relevant:

> (custom-set-variables
>
> ("^pdf$" "." "C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe %o")
>
> '(TeX-view-program-list (quote (("SumatraPDF" "C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe -reuse-instance %o"))))
>
> '(TeX-view-program-selection (quote (((output-dvi style-pstricks) "dvips and start") (output-dvi "Yap") (output-pdf "SumatraPDF") (output-html "start")))))

Now, when I go to pdf-mode of emacs and run the View command then it suggests:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe -reuse-instance "slides.pdf"

but when I press enter nothing happens.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what could be wrong? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Can you take a look at the `*Messages*` buffer, if it shows any errors? Also, you might need to escape the space in `Program Files` using a `\`.

Comment: Furthermore: Your snippet from your `.emacs` seems strange. Line 2 is just a list, without any variable to be customized. I doubt you pasted the contents correctly.

Comment: I found [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52078/sumatrapdf-with-auctex-and-foxit-reader-as-the-default-viewer) and changed the directory under `TeX-view-program-list` to `start` instead of `C:\...` and it works now!